# Non-constant rank of a smooth map and orthnormal basis in the normal bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Assume $M,N$ are two Riemannian manifolds and $f: M\rightarrow N$ is a smooth map. Suppose $dim M =m < dim N =n$.  Let $\Sigma$ be the graph of $f$, that is, $\Sigma =(x, f(x))$ for $x\in M$.  My question is that in the neighborhood of any point $(p, f(p))$ in $\Sigma$, can we choose the $n-m$  orthonormal basis $\{e_{i}\}$ of the normal bundle $N\Sigma$ in the product $M\times N$ such that the projection of $\{e_{i}\}$ into the tangent bundle of $M$ is 0.

When the rank of $f$ is constant in a neighborhood of a point on $\Sigma$, such orthonormal basis is easily to be found. What I am confused is that what's happening when the rank of $f$ is changing in a neighborhood.

Any references are very appreciated.

Comment: I have two confusions about what's being asked: (1) The dimension of the normal bundle of $\Sigma$ in $M \times N$ is $n$, not $n - m$, and it seems like the only way you get a whole basis for $N\Sigma$ projecting to $0$ is for $f$ to be constant. (2) Are you looking for a linearly independent set of vectors in $N_{p, f(p)} \Sigma$ for any point $p \in M$, or are you looking for a set of local smooth sections of $N\Sigma$, or... ?

Comment: Sorry.  I don't look for an orthonormal basic of $N\Sigma$, which dimension is $n$.  I want to construct $n-m$ orthormal frames in $N\Sigma$ in a neighborhood of a point $(p,f(p))$, which is located in $\Sigma$. These frames satisfies that  their decomposition are composed of only in the tangent vector in $TN$.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can't be done, essentially for the rank problems you seem to be struggling with. Consider the map $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by
$$
   f(t) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       (e^{-1/t}, 0) & : t > 0\\
       (0, e^{1/t}) & : t < 0 \\
       (0, 0) & : t = 0
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$
This is obviously smooth for $t \neq 0$, and all of its derivatives are $0$ at $t = 0$, so one checks that it's smooth there as well.

The bundle $N\Sigma$ is parallelizable of rank $2$, and one can identify any of its fibers with the target space $\mathbb{R}^2$ by projection. For $t > 0$, the one-dimensional subspace projecting to $0$ in $T \mathbb{R}$ is the $y$-axis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, while for $t < 0$, it is the $x$-axis, and there's no hope then of getting even a continuous vector field spanning this subspace in a neighborhood of $t = 0$.

Comment: I am not sure where is the problem. In you example,$df_{*}:T_{0}R\rightarrow T_{0}R^{2}$ is not linear.  Actually, in my case, I always assume that $df_{*}$ is a linear map. Maybe some more precise statements can be given.

Comment: In your case, your example is not a smooth map. It is just a map such that all derivatives at 0 are 0.  See [link] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_%28differential%29)

Comment: The function given by $g(t) = e^{-1/t}$, for $t > 0$, and $g(t) = 0$, for $t \leq 0$, has all derivatives defined and continuous at $t = 0$. Therefore $g$ is smooth. By definition, $f(t) = (g(t), g(-t))$, so $f$ is also smooth.